# Custom IIS URL Rewrite Provider in GAC but not showing up in InetMgr

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have written a Custom URL Rewrite Provider. I am able to successfully use it on my local system. However, on the staging environment I am unable to get the dll to list in the "Managed Types" dropdown when I try to add or edit the provider. The dll is successfully added to the gac using gacutil.

The URL Rewriter Dll is built using Visual Studio on my local machine. On the staging environment it is normally built using MSBuild/Jenkins but to be sure, I also built it using Visual Studio.

However, UrlRewriteProvider.dll does not show up. Both the site and the dll use .NET framework 4.5.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have u found any solutions?

Comment: Shashi, have u found any solutions? I am also facing similar issue. add your solution if you have find it.

Comment: I do not remember what was the solution for this. I left the organization where I worked on this. I have however emailed an ex-colleague who worked with me on this to see whether he remembers what the solution was.

Comment: Actually I just saw that I had emailed him when @jorel had commented but haven't received a response. So am not sure if I will get one now. :( Sorry I just can't seem to recollect what the issue was.

Comment: I managed to fix it by setting DLL's target framework to .NET 2.0

Comment: Jorel, so does it mean DLL with framework 4.5 does not support url rewrite? I too managed to fix it by changing the framework to 2.0. But it's strange.

Comment: shashi, no problem. let me continue my investigation